# How to make testcafe respect the `<base>` tag

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, base-tag

My application at some point injects `<base>` tag into the website and after that creates a new `<script>` tag with relative `src`

For example sets `<base href="http://localhost:8080/chapters/de/auth/">` and injects `<script src="build.js" type="text/javascript" />` resulting into browser downloading script from `http://localhost:8080/chapters/de/auth/build.js`.

When running the same application in testcafe, the result is slightly different. Inserted base is  `<base href-hammerhead-stored-value="http://localhost:8080/chapters/de/auth/" href="http://localhost:1337/Lj6CFUfNF/http://localhost:8080/chapters/de/auth/">` and script is `<script src-hammerhead-stored-value="build.js" src="http://localhost:1337/Lj6CFUfNF!s!utf-8/http://localhost:8080/account/build.js" type="text/javascript" />`

Suddenly the previously relative URL `build.js` turned into `http://localhost:8080/account/build.js` which is inconsistent with what is set in `<base>`

Any idea how to get around this?

I am running

testcafe: 1.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the issue is in the order of injecting `base` and `script` tags.
If the `script` element is injected before the `base` element, it will lead to an error.
Please track our progress in the context of
https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3585 issue on GitHub.